# Simplest way of interactively testing a RESTful service?

Tags: javascript, rest

I've recently gotten hold of a Rexster server with a REST API and I've been wanting to play around with it in an interactive way. I've never had to work with REST before, most of my work has been around SOAP and .NET. I'm able to trivially perform all of the GET operations just by navigating to the correct URL through the browser and reading the response with JSONView on Firefox, but anything requiring PUT and DELETE appears to require actual code.

Given that I'm still prototyping and testing the API, I'd like to have a way to interactively throw a bunch of requests at it and see what happens. I'm sure I could concoct something in Java or C# fairly fast, but I'm guessing there's a better way (which is why I was thinking javascript above) and was hoping you folks might recommend one.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, then Fiddler is your best option.  I believe the Mac has an equivalent called Charles.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to debug requests and responses, then Fiddler or HttpScoop is great.  However, for just interacting with the API, I've found that the [Poster plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) for Firefox is the easiest of all.  That sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: I've used Poster in the past, but have started using the REST Console Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) allow you to interact with REST interfaces.

Maybe it won't affect you, but there's a bug in the current open source version that causes every query to be executed twice - took me some time to discover while testing a service that returns an incrementing number :-)